# Get cookie with WT_FPC (WebTrends tracking cookie).

Tags: c#, session, c#-4.0, post, cookies

Tracking POST packages with Fidller, result:

```
POST http://site1.do HTTP/1.1
Host: data.bls.gov
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 12
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://data.bls.gov
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://site1.jsp
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: JSESSIONID=C6395D730AD166AF76AB4E1CC7ECC694.tc_instance3; WT_FPC=id=2859218d72fe8fdf53b1342567507813:lv=1342569213802:ss=1342567507813; fsr.s={"v":0,"rid":"1342592707969_345732","to":2.7,"f":1342594413334}

type=arg1
```

I have to keep cookie to get another site with the same session id. 
So, I use WebClient and extension (CookieAwareWebClient posted on StackOverflow). 
One method is:

```
    private void ReadCookies(WebResponse r)
    {
        var response = r as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response != null)
        {
            CookieCollection cookies = response.Cookies;
            container.Add(cookies);
        }
    }
```

But

```
response.Cookies = JSESSIONID=C6395D730AD166AF76AB4E1CC7ECC694.tc_instance3;
```

Lost information about WT_FPC.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? What type of application is the client (ASP.NET, desktop, Silverlight, ...)? Could you show your full client side code?

Comment: Really, in code there is no magic. My app is desktop, console app, c# 4.0. 
I use WebClient extension to POST/GET values into/from site.

Comment: Anyone know why information about WT_FPC is lost in HttpWebResponse object? I searched through all localc etc. with BugAid and there is no place where can find WT_FPC.

Comment: You didn't answer my request about your full source code. It's difficult to help from the information you provided in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is some more information about code.
So Webclient extension:

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    private readonly CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest r = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        var request = r as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.CookieContainer = container;
        }
        return r;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result);
        ReadCookies(response);
        return response;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        ReadCookies(response);
        return response;
    }

    private void ReadCookies(WebResponse r)
    {
        var response = r as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response != null)
        {
            CookieCollection cookies = response.Cookies;
            container.Add(cookies);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is client code:

```
 using (CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient(Cookies))
        {
            string data = Encoding.Default.GetString(client.DownloadData(m_uri));
            try
            {
                NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection { { "type", "arg1" } };
                string URL1 = "http://x/search.jsp";

                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive] = "true";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip,deflate,sdch";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-US,en;q=0.8";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "max-age=0";

                byte[] result = client.UploadValues(URL1, "POST", values);
                string result1String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
                Console.WriteLine();
}
```

In result1String object i have html site from first website. So nothing happen. 
I use fiddler to investigate. And see my send package doeasnt contain information about WT_FPC. So I try fiddler composer and build own package with that information. And site respond was good!.

So, i try find in code information about WT_FPC, but there isn't.

Comment: Who is supposed to set this `WT_FPC` cookie? Did you ensure that the cookie was set? Is it the first request that you are doing with `client.DownloadData(m_uri)`? Are `m_uri` and `URL1` on the same domain?

Comment: I must set WT_FPC, but first i have to find it in code... Cookie was set I ensured, but only:
JSESSIONID=C6395D730AD166AF76AB4E1CC7ECC694.tc_instance3.

m_uri here is no matter. But yes this is the same domain.

Comment: I don't understand: you want to set this cookie on the client or retrieve it from a an url that set it?

Comment: From URL1 I want response with cookie (session + wt_fpc), so in next POSTing i can use it.

Comment: From what I can see it's not URL1 that emits the cookie. URL1 needs the cookie in the request in order to work normally. I was asking about which url emits this cookie in the response?

Comment: sry my mistake, before first POST, i added:
var site = client.DownloadString(URL1); 
Cookie is added but again no good result with post.

Comment: Could you show the Fiddler output of the request to the `DownloadString` call? I am particularly interested in the HTTP Response headers that the server sends.

Comment: Http response header contain: JSESSIONID=1C81CA8CF609548F37A2A77FA990B2CB.tc_instance3; Path=/oes
So hmm, strange, i think here should be sessionID and wt_fpc, but is only sessionID.

Comment: Saw in fiddler, there is another site between posting, but firstly i ignore it because is img/gif type, but I look closer and saw there is cookies/login

Comment: Thanks Darin, for discussion, you can close subject.

Answer (score 0):

Client site http://site1.jsp have form which i want post.

```
<form name="searchForm" method="POST" **action="/oes/site1.do**">
  <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <P>
          <STRONG>Please select a search type</STRONG>:
        </P>
        <P>
          <INPUT type="radio" name="type" value="arg1" CHECKED />Multiple occupations for one geographical area
        </P>
        <P>
          <INPUT type="radio" name="type" value="occ_geo"/>One occupation for multiple geographical areas
        </P>
        <P>
          <INPUT type="radio" name="type" value="ind_occ"/>Multiple occupations for one industry
        </P>
        <P>
          <INPUT type="radio" name="type" value="occ_ind"/>One occupation for multiple industries
        </P>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Continue">
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```